# nix: install derivation directly from master branch

Tags: nix, nixos

I was wondering, why some packages appear in older versions than in the github repo when querying them via nix-env -qa .. .
I learned that this is due to the fact that the master branch has not been merged to the unstable-channel.

How would I manually install a derivation from the master branch, in order to get the latest version?

Answer (score 9):

Going for the master branch can be a little risky as the binary substitutes might not be available and you can end building lot of packages.
That said, you can specify which `nixpkgs` will be used by `nix-env` with the `-f` flag.

So let's say you want to build `hello` from master, you can use the following:

```
$ nix-env -f https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz -iA hello
```

It is also possible to try git branches packages in a nix shell by using `-I nixpkgs=/path/to/nix/pkgs`:

```
$ nix-shell -p hello -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/master.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 8):

The most flexible way is:

```
git clone https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs
cd nixpkgs
nix-build -A hello
nix-env -i $(readlink result)
```